# Where are the fuel tank sumps on an Aquila A210?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, fuel-tanks

When I drain the fuel I have to do it three times:

> In addition to the drainer openings on both undersides of the wing and under the front fuselage (3 times in total).

Can you tell or show me where the third drainer (under the front fuselage) is located. Do you have a picture of it?

Answer (score 2):

The third drain is at the bottom of the electric fuel pump; [image: as shown on this diagram.] The AT01 is what Aquila calls the AT210 on their web site.

Comment: Is your red arrow pointing to item #12, or to what appears to be a plug on the bottom of item #11? I'd presume the latter, but you know what happens when you ass-u-me... ;)

Comment: The fuel drain fitting is at the bottom of the electric fuel pump. #12 is just a garden variety nut.